# How to upload text files to command "wordcloud" in R

Tags: r, word-cloud

I want to plot a wordcloud using data from a text file in R-Studio but met some problem. How can I upload this text file making it readable by using command "Corpus"?
"text" below is a folder containing a text file named "Twitter_text".

Here are my R code:

```
>FA <- Corpus(DirSource(text))
>inspect(FA)
>FA <- tm_map(FA, stripWhitespace)

>FA <- tm_map(FA, tolower)
>FA <- tm_map(FA, removeWords, stopwords('english'))
>FA <- tm_map(FA, stemDocument)
>FA <- tm_map(FA, removeNumbers)
>FA <- tm_map(FA, removePunctuation)
>FA <- tm_map(FA, PlainTextDocument)
>wordcloud(FA, scale=c(5,0.5), max.words=100, random.order=FALSE, rot.per=0.35, use.r.layout=FALSE, colors=brewer.pal(8, 'Dark2'))
```

When I run the codes: it shows

```
> FA <- Corpus(DirSource(text))
Error in dir(directory, full.names = TRUE, pattern = pattern, recursive = recursive,  : 
  invalid 'path' argument
```

How can R read this text file?
Thanks!!

Comment: Did you try `?Corpus` or corresponding `?VCorpus`?

Comment: Reading `?DirSource`, the argument `directory` should be `A character vector of full path names; the default corresponds to the working directory getwd().`Is the object `text` a character vector/string as described there?

Answer (score 0):

Yiman,

You need to tell Corpus the source type of the data. You can use the `tm::getSources()` function to see the available options to import a corpus with the `tm()` package:

```
> getSources()
[1] "DataframeSource" "DirSource"       "URISource"      
[4] "VectorSource"    "XMLSource"       "ZipSource"
```

In your context, my sense is you want to use a `VectorSource()`. To do this you want to read the text file in as a set of lines using `readLines()`.

I am hoping the example below will help, if you can provide source data (URL, or text file for example) I can go into more detail.

Take care

#### Recommended Reading:

If you are doing analysis of Twitter texts, then I highly recommend you read the following blog:

> http://davetang.org/muse/2013/04/06/using-the-r_twitter-package/

#### Example:

```
if (!require(tm)) install.packages("tm")
if (!require(wordcloud)) install.packages("wordcloud")
if (!require(twitteR)) install.packages("twitteR")
if (!require(SnowballC)) install.packages("SnowballC")
if (!require(RColorBrewer)) install.packages("RColorBrewer")

getSources()

text1 <- readLines("./pg1666.txt")

cor <- Corpus(VectorSource(text1))
inspect(cor)

cor <- tm_map(cor, content_transformer(tolower))
cor <- tm_map(cor, content_transformer(stripWhitespace))
cor <- tm_map(cor, content_transformer(tolower))
cor <- tm_map(cor, removeWords, stopwords('english'))

wordcloud(cor)
```

Result:

[image]